# Dynamically setting a context-root on JSF webapp

Tags: jsf

I have a pretty standard webapp made in JSF 2.0 and Seam 2.2.1 Final. My application.xml lists a context-root as follows:

```
<module>
  <web>
    <web-uri>app.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>app</context-root>
  </web>
</module>
```

My app is being used in four separate instances, however the context-root must differ between instances. The best solution would be to get the database instance name and set it as the context-root (examples: databaseInstance1, databaseInstance2...), but it's not required. Is there a way to set the context-root dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

A Java web server application's root context is set when deployed. Therefore, its root context can't change without redeploying it... at least not without re-writing your own Java web server.

If the separate instances are actually different deployments then you should be able to give each deployment a different `context-root` value. A build tool such as Maven could be used to retrieve the "dynamic" name from the database at build time.